# error: metadata-generation-failed installing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, failed-installation

I have issue when try to execute command `pip install matplotlib` in Command Prompt and Visual Studio Terminal. It starts to install but the following error message appears:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting matplotlib
  Obtaining dependency information for matplotlib from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/39/4c4fb38ec2356bcbc9017a5421623aec69aacde110e4e76d34d0a43702f0/matplotlib-3.7.2-cp310-cp310-win32.whl.metadata
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.2-cp310-cp310-win32.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0.tar.gz (13.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\sofia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kj8pt_5g\contourpy_4a03b4ad473143219945dfde77f9ad5a C:\Users\sofia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kj8pt_5g\contourpy_4a03b4ad473143219945dfde77f9ad5a\.mesonpy-i2w68yex -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\sofia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kj8pt_5g\contourpy_4a03b4ad473143219945dfde77f9ad5a\.mesonpy-i2w68yex\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\sofia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kj8pt_5g\contourpy_4a03b4ad473143219945dfde77f9ad5a
      Build dir: C:\Users\sofia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kj8pt_5g\contourpy_4a03b4ad473143219945dfde77f9ad5a\.mesonpy-i2w68yex
      Build type: native build
      Project name: contourpy
      Project version: 1.1.0

      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\sofia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kj8pt_5g\contourpy_4a03b4ad473143219945dfde77f9ad5a\.mesonpy-i2w68yex\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I also tried with

```
pip install matplotlib==3.5.0rc1

python -m pip install -U matplotlib

pip install matplotlib --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

But none of those worked

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.